# Assess reliability in a pilot study

Tags: reliability, cronbachs-alpha

I'm performing a pilot study in medicine about a new prototype for a diagnostic procedure. The objective of the study is to determine if the prototype is working correctly in order to further develop the device. Is it correct to determine the following two types of reliability:

- the internal consistency using Cronbach's alpha
- stability using the test-retest

Comment: You might need to give more details if you want a more involved answer, but you are correct that Cronbach's alpha is one means of assessing internal consistency, and a test-retest comparison would provide evidence of stability.

Comment: Are the test & retest the same people but after some time has passed? How much?